# How to convert a date/time to MySQL date/time format

Tags: php, datetime

I get some date records like this :
"**Apr 25 2018 03:28:14:000PM**"

I want to convert this format to insert into MySQL table, datetime column.
So, by this example, I expect to obtain "**2018-04-25 15:28:14**"

I know that I can achieve this with substr functions, or switch operators, but I would like the simplest resolution.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/).

Comment: There's something called [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) and there's a nice little function `DateTime::createFromFormat` which, you might have guessed, creates a `DateTime` object from some arbitrary format. And then, the best thing ever, you can use method `DateTime::format` to.. FORMAT the date according to your needs. Isn't it wonderful when you try to read the docs a little bit, or google around a little bit?

Comment: You mean, you didn't bother because there are stupid geeks on SO that will do it for you. It took 5 seconds to find 10 answers dealing with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer you are looking for:

```
$date = new DateTime('Apr 25 2018 03:28:14:000PM');
$formatedDate =  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score -2):

```
$date = date("d-m-Y");

 $query = "INSERT INTO table (date) VALUES ('".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date))."')";
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.